# How do i use react native RCNAsyncStorage module from native swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I have a react native app where I am using `RNCAsyncStorage` npm module for simple data persistence. How ever, my `iOS` version of the app ships with a share extension, and this share extensions needs to access one of my stored data strings.

So in short, I want to use `RNCAynscStorage` from swift native code to get the data which was stored from my react native code.

**Before even trying to implement the module I asked RNC and they replied:**

> This is possible but requires some knowledge of how native modules
>   work in general. I'm not sure how future-proof this is with regards to
>   the upcoming refactoring work in React Native but this is how you
>   could access it today:

```
// First, get the RNCAsyncStorage instance from the bridge
RNCAsyncStorage *asyncStorage = [bridge moduleForClass:[RNCAsyncStorage class]];

// Then call the getter:
[asyncStorage multiGet:@[@"count"]] callback:^(NSArray *response){
    NSObject *count = response[0];
    if ([count isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        // Failed to get count
        return;
    }

    // Use count here
}];
```

However, My extension is written in swift, and I am not sure how this would look when converted to swift.

First I followed a guide to make the react bridge module accessible in swift code, this is how my brinding looks:
[image]

I also tried to convert the objecttive-C example to seift, but this is not working as you can see.
[image]
I am not sure if this is because the module is not exposed/imported correctly, or simply if the swift conversion is wrong. but both `bridge` and `RNCAsyncStorage` is unresolved.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you want to access AsyncStorage in extension(today or share)

I am considering that your extension code will be in swift.

Step 1:
First, you need to create a bridging header in the extension itself, not in the main project.

Step 2:
Declare all the libraries you want to access in Share Extension Target In Link Binary With Libraries (Under Build Phase), especially (libRNCAsyncStorage.a)

Step 3: 
In bridge header file(.h) you have to import RNCAsyncStorage.h

Step 4: Now, access AsyncStore anywhere in the extension.

Comment: Hi thanks, I could really have used that advice/information 7 months ago! :) I ended up writing my own key/value json file to an app.group shared file, and from swift reading and writing to the same file without the use of RNCAsyncStorage at all. But I am sure this would have worked

Comment: which one is a better approach then?

Comment: I think it depends on what needs to be done. In my case it was transferring a single use identity token to sign in the extension to a remote service. For this, I think the true best approach would be to use keychain, but I could not find any way of adding to keychain from react native. I think it's not very trivial to share data between react native and native iOS app, it seem like most developers are doing pure native iOS apps as soon as they become a little complex. I don't think im qualified to say whats best approach ;)

Comment: @Minkoo, I am following the instructions here. But stuck at "React/RCTBridgeModule.h" file not found. Error gets from the bridging header file created at the extension.

Comment: @Erangad Bridging issue. When you create headerFile (Objective C), don't forget to select the target checkbox. One is ofcourse your extension and the main target.

Comment: @Minkoo, thanks for the reply. I had not checked the target check boxes. Now the issue is adding the libRNCAsyncStorage.a under the build phase. When I add the libAsynchStorage.a the error "library not found for -lRNCAsyncStorage" happens. I tried changing library and header search paths for the extension target. But still no help. Do you have a more detail guide? That would be a great help.

Comment: @Erangad Check if AsyncStorage dependency is already in Package.json, If it's already there and you have followed all the steps, then please try to Clean the Yarn or npm and restart Xcode. But be sure you are doing everything right.

Comment: or try to add #import "RNCAsyncStorage.h" in bridge file